# ActivitySwitch method

Tags: android, android-activity, non-static

I'm trying to make an `ActivitySwitch` method. My take looks like this:

```
public class ActivityUtil extends Activity{

    public static void goToActivity(Context contextOfActivity, Class secondActivityClass){
        startActivity(new Intent(contextOfActivity, secondActivityClass));
    }
}
```

I'd like to make it static because there isn't really an object needed for switching activities.

I have few questions:

1. Is there a workaround for calling static methods from non-static?
2. How can I give a class as a parameter? My code gives me an error. I have the right import statements.

I get this warning: "Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class should be parameterized"

Comment: I can't edit my post. Avast is somehow blocking it. So i will poste the warning i get at the definition line of the methode here: "Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized"

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem to call static method from non-static context simply do:

```
ActivityUtil.goToActivity(...);
```

You probably meant calling non-static method in a static context. You will have to call it on the `Context` object passed as a parameter:

```
contextOfActivity.startActivity(new Intent(contextOfActivity, secondActivityClass.class));
```

to pass `Class` object you must do:

```
ClassName.class
```

Comment: i think he will face problem with this in static context , that's right ?

Comment: You can call static methods from non static context with no problems. It's calling non static methods from a static context that is incorrect.

Comment: He's trying to call an instance method (startActivity) from a static method. That's the issue.

Comment: can't use (this) in static context , this error will displayed for him ??

Comment: Yeah I got it the wrong way around and I couldn't find the object I needed for starActivity. Thank you. The thing is i get this warning: "Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized" at the definition line of the methode.

Answer (score 1):

### About `Class` generic parameter warning

First of all there's two simple ways to get a `Class` instance, one static and one dynamic:

```
    ActivityUtil.goToActivity(activity, ActivityToStart.class);  // static, refers a member of a _class_
    ActivityUtil.goToActivity(activity, activityToStart.getClass());  // dynamic, calls a method on an object _instance_
```

The "Class is a raw type" warning refers to *Generics* parameters (or type parameters), not to be confused with e.g. method parameters. You definitely need to read about [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), but you see though that the `Class` class is declared like this:

```
java.lang.Class<T>
```

The `<T>` part here is the parameter the warning is referring to. This `T` gets replaced at compile time by a given type which *you* decide depending on your use case:

```
Class<String> c1 = String.class;  //c1's T refers to the type String
Class<ExampleClass> c2 = ExampleClass.class;  //c2's T refers to the type ExampleClass that you have defined in your code
```

`c1` and `c2` are both instances of the class `Class`, but parameterized with either `String` or `ExampleClass`.

So, in your code, you haven't specified the type of the `T` of `secondActivityClass`, so the compiler doesn't know what to replace it with and issues a warning as it can't make sure whether you won't have a problem at runtime. So what you need to do to remove the warning is specify the value of T, e.g. if you don't know what it'll be:

```
Class<?> secondActivityClass
```

Notice the `?` standing for "any type" for `T`.

That being said, the compiler doesn't have to know what T is here as it won't have any impact, so you shouldn't see this warning. I tried in Idea and I didn't get any warning. Maybe some compiler do, but I'd guess you didn't paste the exact code you're seeing the warning with.

### About non-static context access from static context

There's no "workaround" needed to call `static` methods from wherever, they're just callable. I guess you might forget to state the class in your call, try this:

```
    ActivityUtil.goToActivity(activity, class);
```

I think you also ran into another problem, to call a "non-static" method you need to dereference an object to run the method on. For example in your case you want to do:

```
public static void goToActivity(Context context, Class<?> secondActivityClass){
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, secondActivityClass));
}
```

Notice the `context.` part which refers to the instance you run `startActivity()` on.

In simpler words, `goToActivity()` is static so it is executed from a class, `startActivity()` is not static so it is executed from an instance.

When you write

```
startActivity(new Intent(contextOfActivity, secondActivityClass));
```

this is effectively translated by the compiler to:

```
this.startActivity(new Intent(contextOfActivity, secondActivityClass));
```

But since you're in a static context (Java context, not Android), you don't have any `this` reference at hand and it simply doesn't compile.

---

By the way, I would advise that you think twice about your design. A method which implementation is only one line and not likely to change, just makes the code harder to read and more cluttered. Android provides you with a simple way to "switch" between activities, don't complicates things with wrapping it into your own...

Comment: In this case the caller of goToActivity would have to have a reference to the activity. My guess is he doesn't. That's what's really going wrong.

Comment: That too, possibly. We would have to see its calling code. But anyway the `goToActivity()` wouldn't execute as is because of the lack of instance to call `startActivity()`.

Comment: @user3146659 edited my answer to add information on that raw type warning you're seeing. Consider changing the title of your question to the text of the error you're wanting to fix.

Answer (score 0):

try to make your code like that

```
 startActivity(new Intent(this , secondActivityClass.class));
```

but i think you will face problem with static  with activity context try to remove static keyword

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a static field to hold an instance:

```
private static Activity instance;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    instance = this;

}

public static void goToActivity(Context context, Class secondClass) {
    instance.startActivity(new Intent(context, secondClass));
}
```

**EDIT:** Of course the proper solution would be to not use the static method, and just call startActivity() from an instance of your activity.

This means you will have to pass around Contexts.

For example, if this code to launch an activity is in another class:

```
class MyCode {

    void doStuff() {

        //stuff

        // need to start activity here
    }
}
```

Modify to this accept a context, either to doStuff() or preferably to the obejct's constructor (eliminating redundant Context parameters) Then when you use this from your activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MyCode code = new MyCode(this);

    code.doStuff();

}
```

You can change your doStuff() then to:

```
public class MyCode {
    Context mContext;

    public MyCode(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    void doStuff() {

        //stuff

        // need to start activity here
        mContext.startActivity(....)
    }
}
```

This would be preferable, because otherwise with the static method, maybe the instance is not set? Then what?

You need to pass the context around.